# Como criar um Serviço Background com Genexus Smart Devices em Android?

Tags: android, genexus, services

Desenvolvo com Genexus Smart Devices Ev3 U1 para Android.

Tenho a necessidade que periodicamente uma rotina rode em background e que exiba Notificações.

Tal como o WhatsUp faz, onde há um Serviço deste aplicativo, que exibe notificações mesmo com o aplicativo fechado.

Eu pensei que seria uma Procedure, mas olhei as propriedades e não achei nada parecido.

Como criar um Serviço Background?

Comment: Não precisa colocar em várias línguas, aqui só falamos o português.

Comment: Dependendo do cenário que se quer resolver, as próprias Push Notifications poderiam resolvê-lo de forma mai performante que manter o serviço em background. Mas isso depende se a ação parte do server-side ou não.

Comment: É uma possibilidade que estou imaginando também, eu terei de adaptar o processo para funcionar com Push. Há transações de usuário, como logradouros, que eu vou ter de jogar de OffLine para Online. Também não entendi direito o Push sobre o DeviceToken se ele identifica cada aparelho como único, como obte-lo num código-fonte, se muda e como amarrar essas transações. Grato pelo retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Na sua atividade principal por exemplo você inicia o serviço:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //inicia o serviço
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

    }
}
```

Em seguida tem o seu serviço onde em cada 1 seg verifica se existe alguma notificação e apresenta na barra de notificação do Android, caso o utilizador clique na notificação abre uma atividade:

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    public MyService()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {

    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, final int startId)
    {

            final Handler handler = new Handler();

            handler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if(exist_notification())
                    {
                        create_notification();
                    }

                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                }
            });


        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

/******* criar uma notificação na barra de notificação do android **********/
/******  caso a notificação é clicada abri uma actividade **********/

    private void create_notification()
    {
        try
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Myactivity.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    intent, 0);

            Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.myicon)
                    .setContentTitle(mytitle)
                    .setContentText(myDiscriptonNotification)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            notification_manager = (NotificationManager) this
                    .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notification_manager.notify(null, R.id.main_activity,
                    builder.getNotification());

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```